# EditText Handle color for 28(P) with 29(Q) as target API

Tags: android, android-edittext, customization

So far I've been using reflection so update the selection handle for editTexts. It was working fine up until I updated to target api 29(Q).

It seems like Google did some updates (or Java, not entirely sure), but I now get messages like:

> Accessing hidden field Landroid/widget/Editor;->mDrawableForCursor:Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable; (dark greylist, reflection)

On the upside, api 29 (after many many years) has a stable way of programmatically setting the handle color. Unfortunately it's not backwards compatible as fast as I've been able to discover and it also broke thing for api 28. Anything below api 28 is working just fine with reflection. Below my code  that now works for anything but api 28

```
 /**
 * Sets the color for the cursor and handles on the {@link EditText editText}.
 *
 * @throws EditTextTintError if an error occurs while tinting the view.
 */
public void apply() throws EditTextTintError {
    try {
        // Get the editor
        Field field = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mEditor");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object editor = field.get(editText);

        if (cursorColor != null) {
            editText.setHighlightColor(ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(cursorColor, 40));

            // Get the cursor drawable, tint it, and set it on the TextView Editor
            // Get the cursor resource id
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                ColorFilter colorFilter = new BlendModeColorFilter(cursorColor, BlendMode.SRC_ATOP);
                editText.getTextCursorDrawable().mutate().setColorFilter(colorFilter);
                editText.getTextSelectHandle().mutate().setColorFilter(colorFilter);
                editText.getTextSelectHandleLeft().mutate().setColorFilter(colorFilter);
                editText.getTextSelectHandleRight().mutate().setColorFilter(colorFilter);
            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                try {
                    Field fieldP = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
                    fieldP.setAccessible(true);
                    int drawableResId = fieldP.getInt(editText);

                    // Get the editor
                    fieldP = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mEditor");
                    fieldP.setAccessible(true);
                    Object editorP = fieldP.get(editText);

                    // Get the drawable and set a color filter
                    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(editText.getContext(), drawableResId);
                    drawable.setColorFilter(cursorColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

                    // Set the drawables
                    fieldP = editorP.getClass().getDeclaredField("mDrawableForCursor");
                    fieldP.setAccessible(true);
                    fieldP.set(editorP, drawable);
                } catch (final Exception ignored) {
                    ignored.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                String[] resFieldNames = {"mTextSelectHandleLeftRes", "mTextSelectHandleRightRes", "mTextSelectHandleRes"};
                String[] drawableFieldNames = {"mSelectHandleLeft", "mSelectHandleRight", "mSelectHandleCenter"};
                Integer[] colors = {selectHandleLeftColor, selectHandleRightColor, selectHandleMiddleColor};
                for (int i = 0; i < resFieldNames.length; i++) {
                    Integer color = colors[i];
                    if (color == null) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    String resFieldName = resFieldNames[i];
                    String drawableFieldName = drawableFieldNames[i];

                    field = TextView.class.getDeclaredField(resFieldName);
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    int selectHandleRes = field.getInt(editText);

                    Drawable selectHandleDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(editText.getContext(), selectHandleRes).mutate();
                    selectHandleDrawable.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

                    field = editor.getClass().getDeclaredField(drawableFieldName);
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    field.set(editor, selectHandleDrawable);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new EditTextTintError("Error applying tint to " + editText, e);
    }
}
```

Basically the case for Android P is destroyed by Google's latest update :(

```
else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
    // insert working code here :D
}
```

My question, has anyone been able to programmatically set the handle color using target api 29 for devices that run on api 28?

Just for clarity sake, this is the handle referred to:
[image: Android EditText Handle]

Comment: Extra context, No I do not want to use XML styles to set this. There are plenty of use cases for having this color dynamic. Also I'd like to express my disappointment in Google for this non flexible implementation for customization, which is found in multiple material design classes, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do so with `textField.setTextSelectHandle(drawable)`?

for api < 29

```
// This avoids crash for api < 29: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setTextSelectHandle
    private void setTextSelectHandle(@NonNull EditText editText, @NonNull Context context) {
        try {
            final Field fEditor = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mEditor");
            fEditor.setAccessible(true);
            final Object editor = fEditor.get(editText);
            if (editor != null) {
                final Field fSelectHandleCenter = editor.getClass()
                        .getDeclaredField("mSelectHandleCenter");
                fSelectHandleCenter.setAccessible(true);
                fSelectHandleCenter.set(editor, context.getDrawable(R.drawable.disable_text_handle));
            }
        } catch (ReflectiveOperationException exception) {
            // no-op
        }
    }
```

Comment: On 29+, not on 28.

Comment: @maja89  I edited the code for lower apis, it's in java but should be enough for you to implement the solution.